# CartoDB preferred file type

Tags: carto

I was wondering if anyone knew the preferred upload file type is for CartoDB.I upload zipped .shp files for polygons, and sometimes .csv file for point data. I noticed that when I uploaded a zipped .shp file it hit the 50mb account limit even though the file only ended up being 9mb in cartodb when I upgraded accounts.

Is this becasue it is duplicating the table during processing? Is there a preferred file type for cartoDB? GeoJSON?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I tend to recommend shapefiles, since they retain the type information better than CSV. With CSV you have to change your data type to number if you want to do choropleth and bubble maps.

GeoJSON works too, but will be a bit bulkier to upload.

Hitting the account limit when uploading a 5mb file sounds like it might just be a bug. Could you email support [at] cartodb.com with the shapefile (if you can share it?) - the team can try it out and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll end the file through to support to support to ee what they say.